# Why does a meromorphic function have isolated singularities which must not have a limit point

Tags: complex-analysis

I am self-studying Shakarchi, and the definition of meromorphic is as follows:
[image: meromorphic]

Why should the limit point be excluded from $\Omega$? I am trying to construct an informal proof.

As far as I can see, f is holomorphic on {$\Omega-{z_{0},z_{1}...}$}. Let this sequence converge to say, a.  We have that f is defined on an open set, from the definition of continuity, we have, that if $z_{n}->a$ then $f(z_{n})->f(a)$. Then there are two cases. f is holomorphic at a or not. I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: The point is that $f(z_n)$ doesn't exist, since $z_n$ are singularities. The limit point is excluded because it would be a non-isolated singularity.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos how can I assume it(limit point) will be singular? Which theorem or corollary states that it be singular

Comment: A non-singular point has a neighborhood of non-singular points by definition (within the Taylor series radius) so a limit point of singularities is singular

Comment: @Conrad that's helpful. Can you please elaborate on the definition you are quoting above for non-singular points.

Comment: Non singular points are those where the function is analytic on a small neighborhood of them

Answer (score 1):

I will write the set of singularities as $S$ for short.

Your definition of meromorphicity says that $f$ must be holomorphic on $\Omega-S$. And by definition, holomorphicity is complex differentiability on an open set. So to say that a function is holomorphic on a set implicitly assumes that the set is open. So to even say that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega-S$ we must first make sure that $\Omega-S$ is open, otherwise the expression "$f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega-S$" doesn't make any sense.

Now imagine $\Omega$ contained a limit point $w$ of $S$. Then any open neighborhood of $w$ contains elements of $S$ by definition of a limit point. So any open neighborhood of $z$ contains elements outside of $\Omega-S$. But the definition of an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb C$ is that around every point in $U$ there is an open disc centered at that point completely contained in $U$. The point $w$ from above doesn't fulfill this condition (it is a boundary point of $\Omega-S$), so $\Omega-S$ wouldn't be open. And then a function also couldn't be holomorphic on $\Omega-S$, and then the entire definition of meromorphicity wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Limit point of poles is a non isolated essential singularity and hence the function ceases to be meromorphic. Hence the assumption.